# Use polynomial as function

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I'm pretty new to Mathematica but I'm pretty sure there's an easy way to do it, yet I can't figure it out: if I create a polynomial using InterpolatingPolynomial or similar functions and assign it to a variable (let's call it Poly), how can I transform it in a function callable via

```
Poly[5]
```

to obtain the value of the polynomial at x=5? I know I can use

```
Poly /. x->5
```

for this, but for what I'm doing next I really need Poly to be a callable function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out, it was actually really easy:

```
fPoly = Function[k, Poly /. x -> k];
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is another way:

```
fPoly = Function[x, Evaluate[Poly]]
```

Evaluate[...] is required since Function[...] "holds" its arguments. Alternatively, you can use

```
fPoly = Function @@ {x, Poly}
```

In this latter approach, the head Function isn't applied until after Poly evaluates.

Answer (score 0):

If you have:

```
k = InterpolatingPolynomial[{{-1, 4}, {0, 2}, {1, 6}}, u]
```

Then

```
poly[x_] := k /. u -> x
```